# Figma PDF export order

Tags: pdf, export, figma

When I use the `Export frames to PDF`, I cannot find the way to order the frames as wanted. They seem to be exported in the order they were created. Any idea on how to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I did not get what exactly you are asking, but within the PDF file, each frame will be on its own page, ordered according to its position in Figma, **from top-left** *working* down to **bottom right**.

> You can select all the artboards with having a numerical order i.e. 1, 2, 3 and so on, and export it to pdf in a *specified selected folder/ separate new folder*.
> And then **merge** them/ combine them.

There are many online websites that allow you to merge pdf easily. You can use [this](https://www.ilovepdf.com/merge_pdf) one too to do the same.

Please see the screenshot below

[image]

Then merge it

[image: Video]

Comment: I want to use the `File/export Frames to PDF` option, not the `Export` button at the bottom right side. But anyway, I can sort my frame in the correct order by placing them as you explain :  from top-left working down to bottom right. Thanks!

Comment: Your Welcome! and Welcome to SEGD community :)